# What are "+" and "Ar" in consensus binding sequence of amino acids?

Tags: proteins, sequence-analysis, amino-acids

So I was reading this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10488331) and found a figure as below:
[image]
I understand that **[LEAM]** means any of LEAM residues, **pS** is phosphoserine and **X** means any amino acid residue.

*What is **[+]** here ? Is both **R** and **Ar** arginine itself?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ar` means aromatic and `+` means positively charged residues. However, this is not a [standard](http://www.ddbj.nig.ac.jp/sub/ref2-e.html) code (as of now).

From the same paper:

> Sequences closely matching these optimal binding motifs, R-X-[Ar/S]-[+]-pS-[LEAM]-P and R-[S/Ar]-[+]-pS-[LEAM]-P, denoted as mode 1 and mode 2 consensus sequences, were found to be present in many known 14-3-3 ligands ( Yaffe et al. 1997), **where Ar denotes aromatic residues and + denotes basic residues.**

Answer (score 1):

From the mention of “aromatic residues” in the figure legend (in a different context) *I assume Ar stands for aromatic residues*. *Ar is certainly **not** an abbreviation for arginine.*

I would *guess that [H/+] means either histidine or any positively-charged residue.*

I think that the authors of the paper should have pointed this out in the figure legend, and that the referees should have insisted on it.